# PHP/JS Generate a table-row with 'x' table-data in which case table-data value 'x' is the number of days in current month

Tags: php

I know you can get the days in month with cal_days_in_month(); function, but how do I tell my code to generate exactly 30 or 31 "td" in my "tr" based on exactly the month it is being viewed in. I am making a calendar which will look simple. I will have 2 people and then next to those two people i will have 30 or 31  depending how many days there are on the current month. I unfortunately have no idea how to even start dealing with this problem.

Here is a picture I drew for imagination: [1]: http://prntscr.com/jeg9ft "yes"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in couple of minutes, sorry that I asked this but the thing i wanted is just a simple loop. The thing I was missing was the knowlege of syntax. So I just sat and thought for a couple of minutes and came up with a solution:

```
<?php

$d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,5,2018);
$k=0;
for ($i=1; $i<=$d;$i++){
$k++;
    echo '<td>'.$k.'</td>';
}
?>
```

Now I need to make the `$d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,5,2018);` line work automaticly. I do not want it to be static as it is now, I need it to count the days of the month in which it is being viewed in. So I need a function for $d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,`5,2018`); this part to look for todays month.